# Associative list in Lisp - get all entries of a key from

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, is there a way to retrieve all entries from `alist` that match given key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an assoc list `a`:

```
(defvar a '((a 1) (a 2) (b 1)))
```

You can keep all the pairs that have a car of `a` by calling remove-if-not:

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq (car x) 'a)) a)
```

This results in:

```
((A 1) (A 2))
```

Even though when treated as an assoc list, only the first of those would be returned.

Answer (score 11):

```
(remove 'a '((a 1) (a 2) (b 1))
        :test-not #'eql
        :key #'first)

->

((A 1) (A 2))
```